# Why can't gnome-do find my files?

Tags: gnome-do

I use a handful of files fairly often but Gnome-do can never seem to find them. `Documents/foo/Infrastructure/cheat-sheet.txt` *never* comes up when I type "cheat-sheet" though it is right there if I do `locate cheat-sheet` and I have no trouble bringing up the directory it is in ("Infra..." and it is right there).

What might be going on? Needless to say, this is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest checking the config for your "Files and Folders" plugin. The "Depth" setting on your Documents folder may not be high enough to get down to that level.

Comment: I'm still annoyed. That shouldn't be buried. Do other people not organize work into nested folders?

Comment: It's possible that we should increase the default depth for Documents/.  The problem that having a depth limit is solving is twofold - memory use and Universe pollution.  Do gets progressively less useful the more items it's indexing - it's less likely to bring up the one that you want first - so we tend to try to limit the number of items.

Answer (score 1):

Start gnome-do from command line and see if you get any error messages.

There are comments on launchpad where gnome-do did not work due to a plugin going into an error. 2 examples I found: "Could not locate Skype on D-Bus. Make sure Skype is running" and a uTorrent shortcut in '.local/share/applications/wine' that had  invalid encoding.
Both users found these errors when gnome-do was started from command line and starting skype and removing the invalid torrent file made gnome-do work again.